# Looking For Bitcoin Communities in New York

Tags: client

I'm Interested In Knowing Is there Any Bitcoin Communities that meet Up to Purchase Products Exclusively with Bitcoin In The New York Area?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look on [meetup.com](https://www.meetup.com/find/?allMeetups=false&keywords=bitcoin&radius=25&userFreeform=New%20York%2C%20New%20York%2C%20USA&mcId=c10001&change=yes&sort=recommended&eventFilter=mysugg) for these kinds of groups.